# How to create a 3 column layout like FB while sticking with a grid

Tags: html, css

I'm an engineer. All my designer friends keep telling me to use a grid whatever that means.

I want to create a layout similar to facebook (3 column, with a fat center column. How do I do that while using a grid? Where to even start? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - the question you are asking is off topic here, as it is not programming related. Please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: It is not programming related? Hmm.. :)

Comment: Disagree this is question that leads to a framework. It's like asking if I should use jQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

[960.gs](http://960.gs) is a good system to use.

And, [SmashingMagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/14/designing-with-grid-based-approach/) has a good round-up of examples, articles, tutorials, tools, etc., about grids.

Comment: A google for 'css layout' or 'css grid layout' gave me plenty of samples to pick from.. http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/

Comment: Yes, a google search can get you a lot of results for this sort of thing. Just wanted to give him a starting point from an experienced & trustworthy source. Smashing Mag is reliable & almost always has great stuff to choose from.

Comment: @Max: I agree. Smashing Magazine (and the whole damn awesome network) rocks my world. Anyway, it's good to see people taking the time to suggest excellent resources to those starting out! It's important to start something on the right foot, and the numerous websites out there that provide antiquated, sloppy, or just "plain wrong" information and advice can make that tricky. While I'm commenting, I'd also recommend nettuts+. 
For fun,"webpagesthatsuck.com" provides sobering real-world examples of truly terrible website designs!

Comment: Read the theory (it's really quite simple) then spit out your desired design with a Grid Generator like this:  http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/  It's important to understand what you're doing, but a great programmer is a lazy one......

Comment: Still trying to learn how to use the grid. I generated a 981px grid here (http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php?GridWidth=981&GridColumns=3&GridMarginLeft=20&GridMarginRight=20) Problem is I want the left column to be 181px, I don't see how to do that with the grid system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS framework (I use http://960.gs ) to create a grid. If you were using 960, you would do something like the following:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_3>
        Leftmost
    </div>  

    <div class="grid_6>
        Middle
    </div>  

    <div class="grid_3>
        Rightmost
    </div>
</div>
```

There are other grid systems, this is just one I like the best due to it's lack of learning curve.